# Python ImportError NetCDF4

Tags: python, linux, netcdf

I've been using Python to treat some data that is in netcdf format... Usually I type the code within Pycharm a Python IDE, which I've configure to run the Python scripts with the system install.

To read the .nc files I use the NetCDF4 package and I've no problem when running within Pycharm. However, when I try to run the same script but from the system command line I always got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CheckDate.py", line 2, in <module>
    import netCDF4 as n4
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netCDF4.so: undefined symbol: nc_inq_var_endian
```

Can anybody give me some help to fix this?

Comment: It looks like Pycharm defines a proper `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but on the terminal, that's not set. Where is your `libnetcdf.so` C library? I'm guessing in `/usr/local/lib`, so you should make sure `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to that directory: then the Python module can link with the C library.

Comment: Hello Evert =)

Thank you very much, that was exactly the problem... my LD_LIBRARY_PATH was pointing to other netcdf compilation which does not support netcdf4 

Thank you very much once again